# Incorrect Javascript Date in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, date

I'm getting incorrect dates in Chrome...

My code looks like this..

Title contains "2013-06-14T00:00:00", it was a DateTime in C# returned from WebAPI

As you can see here on both browsers..
[image]

When I add it to a new javascript date like this..
`var dt = new Date(title)`

I get different dates in different browsers...
[image]

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/RvUSq/

Comment: what is the title there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert timestamp to [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) formatted string in C#, for e.g

```
var title = "14 JUN 2013 00:00:00" // printed from C#
```

Then use `Date` constructor

```
var date = new Date(title);
```

If you don't specify timezone the local timezone in the client machine will be set to the given time. If you specify the timezone, needed calculations will be done to convert the date to local timezone.

```
var title = "14 JUN 2013 00:00:00";
var date = new Date(title); // Fri Jun 14 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

var title = "14 JUN 2013 00:00:00 GMT";
var date = new Date(title); // Fri Jun 14 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

var title = "14 JUN 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400";
var date = new Date(title); // Fri Jun 14 2013 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up add a few hours to the date to match my time zone

Answer (score 14):

Looks like Firefox is assuming this datetime format without timezone is local time and Chrome/Webkit is assuming it's UTC.

If the datetime returned from the api is UTC, simply append a "Z" to the end of the string, so it becomes "2013-06-14T00:00:00Z", which indicates the time is in UTC, then you will get the same result in the two browsers.

Comment: appended Z to end.. now both browsers show 6/13/2013.. but string was 6/14/2013, maybe since its 00:00:00 its assuming it was day before?

Comment: Your timezone is EST which is 4 hours behind UTC, so if UTC is 2013-06-14 00:00:00, your local time is 2013-06-13 20:00:00. Therefore, you need to know the timezone of the result you're dealing with.

Comment: @jaux Actually, EST is 5 hours behind UTC.  csharpdev's current timezone is EDT, which is an hour ahead of EST.