# .getDate() and .getMinutes returning different values in Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var getFormattedDateText = function (dateString) {
        var date = new Date(dateString);
        var hours, am_pm, minutes, time;

 //Code for formatting the time starts
        hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
        am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
        time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + am_pm;
//Code for formatting the time ends

        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        console.log(date.getHours() + "=" + date.getMinutes());

        return (monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() +' at ' + time+' Local Time');

    };
```

Here the **datestring is 2017-03-02T09:00:00,**

but in Chrome it is giving **date.gethours()=14** and **date.getMinutes=30**

while in Firefox the **date.gethours()=09** and **date.getMinutes=00**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect Javascript Date in Chrome vs Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334602/incorrect-javascript-date-in-chrome-vs-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying by this solved my issue

```
var date = new Date(dateString + 'Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the way that you inject the date into your function.  I did the following and got the same result in both Chrome and Firefox:

```
getFormattedDateText('2017-03-02 09:00:00');
```

So I removed the 'T' from your dateString.  The browsers both interpret it differently.  When I removed I got the following in the browsers:

```
console.log(date.getHours() + "=" + date.getMinutes());
logged - '9=0'
```

Answer (score 0):

your given date is not in correct format. right date string will return the same value in chrome and firefox.

check the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) for correct formats.

Answer (score -1):

Dates without timezones are handled differently by chrome & firefox.

e.g. add a timezone to your datestring

```
getFormattedDateText('2017-03-02T09:00:00Z'); // UTC timezone
```

Check this [Incorrect Javascript Date in Chrome vs Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334602/incorrect-javascript-date-in-chrome-vs-firefox)

Comment: instead of provide link, try to copy paste the content here